# Using strings inside mBlock extensions code

Tags: programming, c++, string

The following question is about a 3rd party Arduino programming enviroment mBlock and creating extensions for it. I hope that there are some of you out there, who are fammiliar with it.

I was recently making an extensions for mBlock that can be used to write code for Arduino, when I came over this obstacle. I tried to write a function inside the "work":"" statement.

It looked like this:

"work":"Serial.print("Hello world");"

The extensions could not be imported, due to the quotation marks around the Hello world string. I tried removing the quotation marks, the extension was sucessfully added, but the program did not work, beacause quotation marks are needed inside C++ code to define a string.

Is there a way to add them in the extensions, without screwing up the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is a JSON format you could try using single quotes instead of double quotes:

```
"work":'Serial.print("Hello world");'
```

Alternatively you could escape the internal quotes:

```
"work":"Serial.print(\"Hello world\");"
```

Comment: None of the mentioned solutions seem to work. The extensions still do not get uploaded. The extension I am writing has a .s2e extension, if that helps (I am not really familliar with these kinds of files).

Comment: Looking at existing libraries the escaping should work. This is from serial.s2e: `"work":"Serial.print({0});Serial.print(\"=\");Serial.println({1});\n"`

Comment: For some reason it worked this time. I do not not why, but let's just go with it. Thanks.